# Converting a XML to Generic List

Tags: c#, linq, xml-parsing

I am trying to convert XML to List

```
<School>
  <Student>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>dummy</Name>
    <Section>12</Section>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Id>3</Id>
    <Name>dummy</Name>
    <Section>11</Section>
  </Student>
</School>
```

I tried few things using LINQ and am not so clear on proceeding.

```
dox.Descendants("Student").Select(d=>d.Value).ToList();
```

Am getting count 2 but values are like `2dummy12    3dummy11`

Is it possible to convert the above XML to a generic List of type Student which has Id,Name and Section Properties ?

What is the best way I can implement this ?

Comment: I think this article would be useful [Convert XML to Object using LINQ](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/366993/Convert-XML-to-Object-using-LINQ)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create an anonymous type

```
var studentLst=dox.Descendants("Student").Select(d=>
new{
    id=d.Element("Id").Value,
    Name=d.Element("Name").Value,
    Section=d.Element("Section").Value
   }).ToList();
```

This creates a list of anonymous type..

---

If you want to create a list of Student type

```
class Student{public int id;public string name,string section}

List<Student> studentLst=dox.Descendants("Student").Select(d=>
new Student{
    id=d.Element("Id").Value,
    name=d.Element("Name").Value,
    section=d.Element("Section").Value
   }).ToList();
```

Comment: That works perfectly.How do i Convert that to List of Students?

Answer (score 19):

I see that you have accepted an answer. But I just want to show another way which I like. First you will need classes as below:

```
public class Student
{
    [XmlElement("Id")]
    public int StudentID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Section")]
    public int Section { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("School")]
public class School
{
    [XmlElement("Student", typeof(Student))]
    public List<Student> StudentList { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize this xml:

```
string path = //path to xml file

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(School));
    School school = (School)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: I know this was answered 9 years ago, but I just came across this answer to solve a problem and it worked exceptionally well. However I'm curious how exactly the StudentList attribute is filled after the ```using``` chunk of code. At what point is the serializer filling this attribute list with student objects?

Answer (score 1):

```
var students = from student in dox.Descendants("Student")
           select new
            {
                id=d.Element("Id").Value,
                Name=d.Element("Name").Value,
                Section=d.Element("Section").Value
            }).ToList();
```

or you can create a class call Student with id, name and section as properties and do:

```
var students = from student in dox.Descendants("Student")
           select new Student
            {
                id=d.Element("Id").Value,
                Name=d.Element("Name").Value,
                Section=d.Element("Section").Value
            }).ToList();
```