# How would I parse an XML file into a list

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

List:

---

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
```

XML File:

---

```
<memberlist>
 <member>
  <name>Name</name>
  <status>Status</status>
 </member>
</memberlist>
```

How would I go about parsing this file, lets say (file.xml) into the list?

I've tried many ways but none of them seem to be working.

I want to check to see if the status is 'gold', and if it is, I would like to put the name of that member into the list.

Comment: Your xml describes a hierarchy, what exactly do you want to end up with in your list? Show expected result.

Comment: Have a look at [xml-to-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297583/converting-a-xml-to-generic-list)

Answer (score 0):

Load the xml into an `XDocument`. You can do this from a file, I have demonstrated from a string.

Do a linq query for elements named "status" (within "member") that also have a value of "gold".

Of those, grab the value of the "name" element.

Use `AddRange` on your list of strings.

```
List<string> lstGolds = new List<string>();

string xml ="<memberlist><member><name>Name</name><status>gold</status></member></memberlist>";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var goldStatus = doc.Descendants("member")
    .Where(d => d.Element("status").Value == "gold")
    .Select(d => d.Element("name").Value);

lstGolds.AddRange(goldStatus);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ

```
XElement xml = XElement.Load("locationToYourXmlFile");

var members = xml.Elements("member");
var list  = members.Where(member => member.Element("status")?.Value == "Gold")
                   .Select(member => member.Element("name")?.Value)
                   .ToList();
```

Assuming your XML has a bunch of member elements under the root `memberlist` element, each with a `name` and `status` element inside that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<memberlist>
    <member>
        <name>John</name>
        <status>Gold</status>
    </member>
    <member>
        <name>Sam</name>
        <status>Silver</status>
    </member>
    <member>
        <name>Sara</name>
        <status>Gold</status>
    </member>
</memberlist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your XML to a list of objects....

Use these two mehods:

```
public static string Serialize<T>(T dataToSerialize)
{
    try
    {
        var stringwriter = new ISOEncodingStringWriter();
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        var xns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        xns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

        serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, dataToSerialize, xns);
        return stringwriter.ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}

public static T Deserialize<T>(string xmlText)
{
    try
    {
        var stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(xmlText);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Make the following Class where you give the following attributes

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Members", Namespace = "")]
public class Members
{
    [XmlElement("Member")]
    public Member[] member { get; set; }
}

public class Member
{
    [XmlElementAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElementAttribute("Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize your data.

```
Members result = Deserialize<Members>(XML_String);
```

You got your members in a array and you ca convert that to a list if you want.

Answer (score -1):

You should use using System.Xml.Linq;

```
using (FileStream fileStramWrite = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))   
 using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStramWrite))
                    {
                        var xdoc = XDocument.Load(streamReader);
                        var xElement = xdoc.Element("memberlist");
                        var xElement2 = xElement.Element("member");
                        var name = xElement2.Element("name").Value;
                        var status = xElement2.Element("status").Value;
                    }
```

Comment: If you have a lot of member, that do:

IEnumerable<XElement> members= xElement.Elements("memberlist");
      foreach (XElement member in members){
list.Add(member.Element("name"));
}

Comment: It doesn't work. I get the error...

Cannot implicityly convert System.Xml.Linq.XElement to System.Xml.Linq.XDocument

from...
XDocument xElement = xdoc.Element("memberlist");
                
XDocument xElement2 = xElement.Element("member");

Comment: It still doesn't work. All variables are returned null.